# Elasticsearch simple search with contains across multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

I have a system with many fields, and our requirement is that when you search for a term, it searches many fields to return as part of an auto complete.

For instance, in one box you might search for a company name, company address line 1, postal code, phone number, etc. If you type `my co` this would match company name `my company`, typing `612 wharf` would match address line 1 of `612 wharf ave`, for example.

I have found many examples of different ways to search elastic, but I have not been able to find the right configuration to do this simple kind of search. I have tried setting my fields up as `text` with `field_data`, and this works in some cases but not in others. Searching with spaces tends to not work with my query string. That is, searching for `612` would result in `612 wharf ave` but `612 wharf` would not.

**What field analyzers should I have, and what type of searches should I be doing in this use case?**

Options i have found for analyzers:

- Text analyzer
- Text analyzer with field data
- Keyword (does not work because i won't be typing the full value each time)
- [Custom autocomplete analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_index_time_search_as_you_type.html)

Options I have found for searching:

- QueryString
- MultiMatch
- Suggest (does this work with multi-field? i couldn't find out how)
- Match (doesn't work with multi field)

I have tried most of these combinations but I have not found one that works as I want. **All I want is a simple contains search across multiple fields**, and nothing I've tried seems to work.

Table of example searchs:

```
Search    | Expect to get company that has this field | In my testing:
612       | Line1: 612 wharf ave                      | this works with querystring
612 wharf | Line1: 612 wharf ave                      | doesn't work with QS
comp      | Name: My Company                          | works with QS
my co     | Name: My Company                          | doesn't work with QS
```

Comment: i think i may have finally found the answer, which is to put quotes around the search term, so my query string looks like `"\"612 wharf\""` in the json

Comment: nope. adding quotes around the search term makes `612` not return `612 wharf`. I can't win.

Comment: Having the exact same issue. How is this so hard?!